# TCP Client unintentional sending

Tags: c#, visual-studio, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I coded a **client => relayserver => client** application for desktopsharing, But after sending the first image the Client is sending a massive ammount of random data, some filled with random data, some filled with zeros.

Sending/Receiving Code:

```
    public static byte[] receive(TcpClient cl)
    {
        byte[] bsize = new byte[3];
        cl.GetStream().Read(bsize, 0, 3);
        int s = (bsize[0] * 65025) + (bsize[1] * 255) + bsize[2];
        if (s == 0)
        {
            cl.GetStream().Flush();
            return null;
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[s];
        cl.GetStream().Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        return data;
    }

    public static void send(TcpClient cl, byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] sdata = new byte[data.Length + 3];
        sdata[0] = (byte)(data.Length / 65025);
        sdata[1] = (byte)((data.Length - (sdata[0] * 65025)) / 255);
        sdata[2] = (byte)(data.Length % 255);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sdata[i + 3] = data[i];
        }
        cl.Client.Send(sdata);
        Console.WriteLine("Data send (" + (sdata.Length - 3) + ")");
    }
```

In the beginning i send an authcode of 12 bytes (9 + 3), that works without a problem. But when i send an image, with the code below:

```
    private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (c != null) // c is a TcpClient
        {
            var x = s.getScreenCopy();

            byte[] data = ConnectionHandler.getBytes(x);
            byte[] sdata = new byte[data.Length + 1];
            sdata[0] = (byte)(Command.Image);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sdata[i + 1] = data[i];
            }
            ConnectionHandler.send(c, sdata);
        }
        else
        {
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
```

The client keeps sending random data. The serverlog looks like this:

```
Starting TechViewer Server... Done.
 Listening for Customer on port 30001
 Listening for Supporter on port 30000
New connection from: 79.224.122.xxx
Received data with length: 9
First byte: 115
Supportkey Received
Generated new id: 174104133
Send data with Length: 3 ...Done.
Added Supporter
New connection from: 79.224.122.xxx
Received data with length: 9
First byte: 99
Clientkey Received
Waiting for Sessionnumber from Client
Received data with length: 3
Id received: 174104133
Trying to set Client
compareing 174104133 with 174104133
Trying to Add Client to connectedClients
Sent id to Client
Send data with Length: 3 ...Done.
Client Set
Received data with length: 188915 from 79.224.122.xxx
Relay to Supporter
Send data with Length: 188915 ...Done. // This is the correct Package
Received data with length: 14231165 from 79.224.122.xxx
Relay to Supporter
Send data with Length: 14231165 ...Done. // Random data
Received data with length: 16006753 from 79.224.122.xxx
Relay to Supporter
Send data with Length: 16006753 ...Done. // Random data
```

The weirdest thing is even if i set a breakpoint in the application it keeps on sending massive ammounts (between 30 - 160 mb)

So why does this happen and how could i prevent this?

Addition:

Servercode for relaying the data:

```
    public void relayData(object state)
    {
        try {
            TcpClient tclient = (TcpClient)state;
            while (true) {
                byte[] bytesFrom = ReadFrom(tclient);
                if (client == tclient) {
                    RelayToSupporter(bytesFrom);
                }else{
                    RelayToClient(bytesFrom);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void RelayToSupporter(byte[] data)
    {
        if (supporter.Count > 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("Relay to Supporter");
        }
        foreach (var item in supporter) {
            try {
                if (item.Connected) {
                    send(item, data);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RelayToClient(byte[] data)
    {
        if (client.Connected) {
            Console.WriteLine("Relay to Client");
            send (client, data);
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Things i tried:

- sending only one Image and then stop sending (Result: no change)
- sending in manually created chunks smaller then the MTU (Result: no change)

Things i noticed:

- i think my packet calculation is off somewhere, so the overlapping bytes are interpreted as size, which is obviously even more wrong.

Still didn't found the error in my code.

Comment: Do you stop your timer while you send the data? Sending raw images of the entire desktop is a lot of data, and especially expensive considering you do a byte-by-byte `for` loop to copy one buffer to another. You may be having issues with overlapping timer calls which can stack up. Remember that packets have a finite size, usually around 1500 bytes, so your send takes multiple packets to complete.

Comment: @RonBeyer as you can see in the serverlog the image data is around 200kb (i verified it by looking how big the image is before sending). the for loop takes at most 2ms and ther timerintervall is 200ms. I even tried to send an Image just once and it gave me the same result

Comment: To send 200kb of data will take 133 packets, if using TCP each one has to make a round-trip meaning the receiver has to acknowledge the packet before the sender can send another. Even if the packets could be sent at the rate of 1 per ms, you are looking at 266ms to send the data. From your description, your events are piling up since threads continue to run in the background when pausing. You need to take into account the transmission time too.

Comment: By the way, [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) is much more efficient at copying byte data from one buffer to another.

Comment: @RonBeyer how do you determine how big one packet is? isnt that the receiving/sendingbuffersize?

Comment: No, a packet is not really allowed to be larger than the defined "Maximum Transmission Unit" or MTU. While theoretically the MTU can be as large as 65535 bytes, the most common value for the MTU is 1500 bytes. Search google for MTU size. Packets larger than the MTU are broken down into multiple packets <= MTU in length.

Comment: What's the code for `RelayToSupporter` and `RelayToClient`?

Comment: And my calculation is a little wrong, it doesn't take into account the packet header and CRC, so it will actually take more than 133 packets to send.

Comment: @Iridium i edited my question with the code.

Comment: There's still a lot of code you're not showing us, which makes diagnosing your problem more difficult - e.g. you've not showed `ConnectionHandler.getBytes(x)` (have you confirmed it's returning the correct sized byte array each time, or is it the source of your random data), your "server log" also has lines that aren't logged by any of the code you've shown, etc. You need to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Iridium i thought that would be too much code for a question, but i could post it on pastebin

Answer (score 0):

One very likely source of problems is the assumption in your calls to `cl.GetStream().Read(...)` that it will fully fill the provided buffer, which is not necessarily the case. Your initial image buffer may therefore not be getting filled completely, and so on your next `receive()` the bytes you're interpreting as the size header are actually bytes from the middle of the first image, giving you the unexpected sizes.

Any time you `Read(...)` from the network stream, you need to inspect the return value to determine how much data (*if any*) was returned.

I would suggest using a helper like this if you want to read a specific number of bytes from the stream:

```
private byte[] ReadData(TcpClient client, int numBytes)
{
    var data = new byte[numBytes];
    var totalBytes = 0;
    while (totalBytes < data.Length)
    {
        var bytesRead = client.GetStream().Read(data, totalBytes, data.Length - totalBytes);
        if (bytesRead == 0) break;
        totalBytes += bytesRead;
    }
    if (totalBytes != data.Length)
    {
        // This will occur when the other end of the connection is closed (and so Read() returns zero).
        // You can throw an exception, return null etc. depending on your requirements
        ...
    }
    return data;
}
```

This should be used whenever you want to read an exact number of bytes from the stream, even for just your 3-byte size header, since this could come through in e.g. 3 separate 1-byte `Read()`s.

I'd also note that your calculation of the byte values for your header is rather strange. You may want to look into expanding to a 4-byte header (the size if bytes of `int`) and then taking advantage of the framework's `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)` and `BitConverter.ToInt32(...)` to convert the size to a byte array and back again.